# 2013 Ford Transit Connect 2.0L engine R/R Transmission estimated Labor times?

Tags: ford, transmission, replace, transit

What website can I utilize to find the estimated labor hours for the removal and replacement of a transmission, including all fluids for a 2013 Ford Transit Connect with a 2.0L engine? Or does anyone know the approximate time it should take to remove and replace a transmission? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!